# How to identify each table when using MultiTableMixin

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'm using MultiTableMixin to display 4 tables on a page. The tables are being rendered just fine using `{% render_table table %}`. I'd like to add a header to the table describing what each table is. I tried adding something in the table Meta like so:

```
class PeopleTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        title = "Table about people"

class FruitTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        title = "Table about fruit"
```

Then tried to access this in the template with `{{ table.title }}` but that didn't work. Is something like this possible?

Or can I access the model for each table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the title as an attribute on the table like this:

```
class PeopleTable(tables.Table):
    title = "Table about people"

class FruitTable(tables.Table):
    title = "Table about fruit"
```

and access them with `{{ table.title }}`.

Comment: Nice! I simply had my title declared in the wrong place.